# How to reverse this for loop in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I reverse this for loop, I want the locations to be in opposite.

```
for i, v in enumerate(totals):
    plt.text(v + 3, i + .25, str(v), color='blue', fontweight='bold')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reversed`:

```
for i, v in enumerate(reversed(totals)):
    plt.text(v + 3, i + .25, str(v), color='blue', fontweight='bold')
```